# How to remove duplicate songs from itunes playlist?

Tags: itunes, music

How to remove duplicate titles from itunes playlist ?
When adding directories with mp3s to itunes that contains playlist files, it's listing twice (or more) the songs in the album view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes actually has a feature to display duplicates. It shows you all songs which it thinks are the same and you can delete one of them.

Here is a support page from Apple explaining how: [Link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201812)

Comment: Is this feature available on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: That feature only shows you duplicate songs in your library. It does not show duplicate songs in a playlist, which was as I understood the question.

Answer (score 4):

After selecting the playlist you would like remove duplicates from in iTunes, you'll then want to select "*Name*" in the "*Sort By*" menu (located under the "*View*" main menu item).

[image: iTunes Sort Playlist by Name Menu Item]

This will sort the songs in alphabetical order to where you can easily identify any duplicates since they'll appear right next to each other.

You'll then want to select a duplicated song and hover over the selected song to reveal the ... (More) menu.

[image: iTunes Song More Menu Appears to the Far Right on Hover]

Then select "*Remove from Playlist*" to delete the selected duplicated song.

[image: iTunes Remove Song from Playlist Menu Item]

And, just in case you're wondering, yes – doing this operation will only delete the selected duplicate, not all instances of the song within the playlist. (Which was a secret worry of mine.)